# How to install Android through CWM after accidentally deleting it

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, installation

I have the Android phone Lava Iris X1. Unfortunately I have deleted my operating system in my phone. I want to install a new version of Android (Lollipop) on my phone with the help of Clockworkmod recovery. Please help me to do this.

Comment: It's vital to search for some information, before attempting to change your system or parts of it. It's not too trivial of a task.

Comment: sir my operating system is deleted how can i recover please help me to fix this problem

Comment: @Death Mask Salesman i am make backup and search all knowledge about them but unfortunately my Operating system is deleted Please help me To fix this